# Spring MVC - Asynchronous Request Processing

Tags: multithreading, spring-mvc

I'm trying to design and implement a system, building on the ability to extend functionality of the Windows NPS service, when authenticating for a VPN service, through use of an extension DLL. The extension DLL, written in C, posts some information about the authentication attempt to a REST based servlet. This servlet is responsible for sending a code through email to the email address of the person authenticating. The user will have to authenticate himself through entering this code in an Android application, which sends this code back to the servlet for checking. If the code received from the user corrosponds the code sent previously in the process, the servlet will respond to the DLL's HTTPClient with a status code signaling the successful authentication process.

I'm struggling to find a proper solution for handling the authentication code checking. I want to handle the request from the DLL, send the email, and wait for the user to send the authentication code back through the Android application. My first thought was make use of the Spring MVC framework, and utilize "Asynchronous Request Processing" (https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application). However, I do not have a proper solution yet.

My idea was to have two separate method, one mapped to handle to request from the DLL, the other to handle the request from Android application. The method mapped to handle the request from the DLL should sleep until interrupted by the method mapped to handle the request from the Android application and check if the authentication code matches.

This idea sounds good to me, but I cannot find any pointers as how to implement this idea. Also an issue what dawned on me is that there might be multiple threads, waiting for an interrupt. How do I handle that the correct Android mapped method interrupts the matching DLL mapped method?

Could anyone give me some pointers where to look, or adjust my train of thought to a better way to handle this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after a dirty yet creative way of using an Callable/Runnable hybrid. Add the Callable to the pool, and use the Callables class to implement Runnable aswell, to make sure you can "interrupt" the Callable.